# Coverting list into a Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe(gh) in which second coloumn contains Json strings.

```
>ty<- gh[1,2]
>ty
"{\"color\":\"Multi\",\"size\":\"M\",\"material\":\"Cotton\",\"occasion\":null,\"rise\":null,\"length\":null,\"pattern\":\"Checks\",\"sleeve\":\"Full Sleeves\",\"neck_type\":null,\"fit\":null,\"bra_type\":null,\"wiring\":null,\"color_filter\":\"Multi\",\"type_filter\":null,\"type\":null,\"gender\":\"Men\"}"
```

On applying fromJson() in this string i get a list as follows.

```
>fromJson(ty)

ty
$color
[1] "Multi"

$size
[1] "M"

$material
[1] "Cotton"

$occasion
NULL

$rise
NULL

$length
NULL

$pattern
[1] "Checks"

$sleeve
[1] "Full Sleeves"

$neck_type
NULL

$fit
NULL

$bra_type
NULL

$wiring
NULL

$color_filter
[1] "Multi"

$type_filter
NULL

$type
NULL

$gender
[1] "Men"
```

I want to convert this list in a data frame i have tried rbind with unlist and everything google could offer but every timei get a data frame it comes in this format.

```
> as.data.frame(unlist(ty),stringsAsFactors = F)

               unlist(ty)
color               Multi
size                    M
material           Cotton
pattern            Checks
sleeve       Full Sleeves
color_filter        Multi
gender                Men
```

But if i use unlist on ty i get

```
>unlist(ty)
  color           size       material        pattern         sleeve   color_filter         gender 
       "Multi"            "M"       "Cotton"       "Checks" "Full Sleeves"        "Multi"          "Men"
```

Which is a character vector.

I want first column to be first row and the entries corresponding to second column should come in second row followed by more more such rows as i have almost 70000 json strings and the column name of those strings may or may not have same column name.
Please help me with this problem.

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(gh[,2], fromJSON))`. Does this give what you want?

Comment: Can you give an example of the output your expecting?

Comment: Thank you @Psidom it worked, though i figured i can use transpose function to get desired result but your method is short and sweet.